# Android Location issues

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to understand Android location found a lot of code on the web, they all look different and they juggle with the libraries in different ways that confuses me. I wasn't able to find a commonly used approach.

Basically I need to get the location using GPS, if the location is not successfully retrieved within 90 seconds using the GPS, then get the location provided by the network. What is the simplest way to do that?

I tested the following snippet but the results on the device are not robust sometimes is not clear how to make sure, that getLastKnownLocation() is not getting a old stored location that is not current. Thanks!

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
    gps_latitude = location.getLatitude();
    gps_longitude = location.getLongitude();
    gps_timestamp = location.getTime();
    gps_accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    gps_provider = location.getProvider();
    gps_speed = location.getSpeed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the [LocationCLient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) to get the best last known location available. This class uses a mix of GPS, WiFi and sensors to detect the current location for you automatically. So there is no need to decide between GPS or network anymore.

Here's a [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) how to use it.

EDIT: You have to use the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) library, which is compatible to API 8.

Answer (score 1):

A bit tardy for the party, but figured it would be worthwhile to post an update for people reading this in 2016 (or later).

As other answers have suggested, the best way nowadays is to use the **Google Play Services Location API**.
Unless you really need fine-grained control of the location providers, the Google API is bound to give you a better location estimate in a shorter time, using only the resources (GPS, WiFi, Cell Tower, Bluetooth) that are actually required on each user's device.

Unfortunately, subscribing to location updates can still be a hassle (as [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527690/6424399) pointed out, the API is a bit more complex). You need to do some or all of the following:

- *Once:* Ask for location permission (Marshmallow and above)
- Connect to the API, handle different errors and corner cases
- Check and possibly enable required location providers
- Request location updates

I struggled with setting up location updates in several different projects and decided to write a utility class that does most of the work for you:

[LocationAssistant - Hassle-free location updates on Android](https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant)

I also wrote a detailed blog post about setting up Android location on a wide range of Android versions, which you can [read here](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/05/27/location-on-android-stop-mocking-me/).

---

So, to solve your original problem (get an up-to-date location with GPS accuracy as quickly as possible):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationAssistant.Listener {

    private LocationAssistant assistant;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        // You can specify a different accuracy and interval here, depending on the needs of your app
        assistant = new LocationAssistant(this, this, LocationAssistant.Accuracy.HIGH, 5000, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        assistant.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        assistant.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewLocationAvailable(Location location) {
        // Do something with the location
    }

    ...
}
```

`onNewLocationAvailable()` is invoked as soon as the first valid location is available. There are some more listener methods you need to implement to deal with situations in which permission is not granted or location providers are switched off. But essentially this is it.

The **LocationAssistant** also allows you to reliably reject mock locations (in case that's a requirement for your app).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to prioritize GPS location so hard? There are a couple of disadvantages to having a hard requirement on the GPS provider:

1. You have to use the oldest API, since that's the only one where you can explicitly force which "type" of fix you retrieve. (The 'LocationManager')
2. It's usually significantly worse from a user experience standpoint, since it takes longer to get a GPS fix, it won't work indoors etc.
3. The newer API's have a lot of nifty logic where things like battery life, quickness, accuracy etc. can be weighed.

I don't know anything about your application of course, just tipping you to think about what your real requirements are.

There are other benefits to the "new" api's, which i discovered firsthand when switching in our app about 18 months ago:

It is quicker and more reliable.
it is less buggy. As an example, in the old API we could sometimes get an "old" fix with a new timestamp. This never happens anymore. There's more but it would be an even more lengthy post.
It definitely drains less battery. For example, when you had a map view open, the GPS ran all the time, and the GPS icon was visible. This is not the case with the new one. This made users wonder what was going on. This is nolonger as big an issue.
So, when it comes to the location output and work, everything is better. But there are some downsides:

You have to have Google Play Services installed, meaning it wont work on any "non-google-approved" phone models, and in some instances you'll have to tell users they need to install it.

The API itself is more complex IMO, in part due to point 1. In addition to the "regular" callbacks i.e. waiting for location fixes etc. You now have a process that takes part before you can get started where you have to check that playservices is available, and "connect" the locationclient. This is extra code and a bit more complex to grasp. More faulty conditions to take into account in the code too (if you can be bothered...)

Google play services itself requires at least 2.2 so it won't work for older devices than that. We had to tell some clients they had to upgrade...

Hope this helps!